# How to avoid users adding a user stored procedure name like sp_%

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

Someone told me that **DMF management policy and condition** can do this. Does anybody know how to implement this.

Comment: DMF? Also, what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this through Policy Based Management.  You create a **Condition** for a procedure **Facet** with the parameter *@Name* to be `NOT LIKE` 'sp_%'.  Then you create a **Policy** for that **Condition** and you can enforce this on demand or on a schedule.

Comment: Beware that the pattern `sp_%` matches any name starting with the letters `sp` and containing at least one more character, since `_` is a special character. I think the pattern `sp[_]%` would work.

Comment: Also, the policy system lets you *detect* that something has been done wrong, but doesn't prevent it happening in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open SQL Management Studio
2. Go to "management" -> Conditions -> Create new condition
3. Enter a name for the condition.
4. Select Facet "Stored Procedure"
5. Enter in the column "Field" @name
6. Enter in the column "Operator" NOT LIKE
7. Enter in the column "Value" 'sp[_]%'
8. Click on OK to save
9. Create a policy. Go to "management" -> Policy -> Create new Policy
10. Enter a name for the Policy
11. Select the name of the condition in the dropdown menu "check condition"
12. Set "Evaluation Mode" to 'On change:Prevent'
13. Enable the policy
14. Click on OK to save and enable the policy
15. Test the policy by entering a new query

> CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
>      @LastName nvarchar(50), 
>      @FirstName nvarchar(50) 
>   AS
>
> SET NOCOUNT ON;
>      SELECT FirstName, LastName, Department
>      FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory
>      WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName
>      AND EndDate IS NULL;
>   GO

This result in :

> Policy 'StoredProcNamingPolicy' has been violated by >    > 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\DB01\DEFAULT\Databases\MyDB\StoredProcedures\dbo.sp_test'.
>    This transaction will be rolled back.
>    Policy condition: '@Name NOT LIKE 'sp[_]%''
>    Policy description: ''
>    Additional help: '' : ''
>    Statement: 'CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
>      @LastName nvarchar(50), 
>      @FirstName nvarchar(50) 
>    AS
>
> SET NOCOUNT ON;
>      SELECT FirstName, LastNam...'.
>    Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_syspolicy_dispatch_event, Line 65
>    The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.